# android: custom intent is triggered first

Tags: android, sms, broadcast

I am writing an app to receive the sms and display it on my screen. I declared a broadcast receiver and registered in my activity (in oncreate()). I haven't set any priority in my manifest file as well. 
However during run time, my receiver is receiving the sms first then  the systems message service is invoked first. Is this the behavior of custom broadcast receivers?

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android sends ordered broadcasts for SMS messages.  From the [reference guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) (emphasis mine)

> Ordered broadcasts (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are
>   delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in
>   turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can
>   completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other
>   receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the
>   android:priority attribute of the matching intent-filter; **receivers
>   with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.**

I suspect that due to the lack of priority, the order is being chosen arbitrarily.